# Awk,why is zero not being read when inputted in code?

Tags: awk

```
/[0-9]+/{ 
    if (NR >= 1){
        if ($0 != 0 &&  NF == 1)
        {       #if the line is not 0
            if ($0 !~ /[A-Za-z]/)  
            {  #if it contains no letters
            printf("no good \n")
            }
            
        } 
        
        else if ($0 == 0)
        {
            printf("This is good \n") # this needs to execute when only zero is inputted  
        } 
}
}
END{
   
}
```

So the loop works with all other numbers. It will execute correctly when 2 zeros are entered or when 1 zero is entered and a blank line is left after. But I need it to execute when just a zero is entered, no blank spaces or a blank line is placed after the zero, any ideas?

Edit:
I don't know how to show but when there is no output at all when just a zero is entered for me. I am also using an online compiler called **coding ground in awk**, maybe that is the issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for sharing your code attempt, could you please do add sample of your input and expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: When I run your program on a one-line file containing only a single 0, I get "This is good". So either I'm misunderstanding your problem or you have an issue with your data rather than your code.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output, not just a description of the input but actual input that fails the way you say it does and show us the exact command line you run to produce the failure. Also, this wouldn't cause your problem but wrt `/[0-9]+/{ 
    if (NR >= 1){` - think about under what conditions `/[0-9]+/`can be true while `NR >= 1` is false, i.e. your current input line contains digits but the current input line number is zero or negative.

Comment: Please stop posting links and images in your questions and simply include text inline in your question as you've been asked to do multiple times in questions you've posted under your current login and your other alias (https://stackoverflow.com/users/13314859/polikujm). See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: If you suspect that running your code on `an online compiler called "coding ground in awk"` is the issue then try your code on some other platform to see. For example if you have a laptop running Windows then install cygwin and test your code in that. I do wonder if your script is reading from stdin and you're typing `0` without then hitting the "Enter" key to generate the newline that'd cause awk to read that input.

Comment: Can you test your script with something like `printf "1 2\n2 3\n0\n4 5\n" | awk 'myscript'` ? If yes, then please edit your Q to show that test. Good luck.

Comment: @EdMorton so my script is reading from stdin and then I'm "typing 0 without then hitting the "Enter" key to generate the newline", which is my problem, is there a workaround in not having to hit enter after the zero?

Comment: Nothing springs to mind within awk itself. You could always pipe input to awk 1 char at a time from a shell while-read loop that reads 1 char at a time ([google unix+shell+read+input+without+hitting+enter](https://www.google.com/search?q=unix+shell+read+input+without+hitting+enter)) that's if, of course, you want to process 1 char at a time. That'd look something like `while IFS= read -r -n1 char; do printf '%s\n' "$char"; done | awk 'script'`

Comment: Actually - if you have GNU awk you could maybe use the feature described at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Read-Timeout. I've never used it so idk any more about it.

Comment: @EdMorton alright, thanks for the help

Comment: Do you just need `else if ($0 == "0")` to prevent "false positives"?